# How to provide download of APK file from google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, download

I put my android application on the google app engine(python) to let others to download it.

But I don't know how to implement such function by python and the format of android application file is APK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use the python bits really you just need to setup your app.yaml file to serve static files.

You'll need to add a directory to the root of your appengine project called something like 'public', place your apk in that directory and then add the following to your app.yaml

```
handlers:
- url: /public
  static_dir: public
```

After you deploy your file will be available at *yourappid.appspot.com/public/yourfile.apk*

See [Serving static files](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/staticfiles.html)

I'd recommend placing your app on [market.android.com](http://market.android.com) rather than appengine though.... your users will be able to find it easily and recieve updates as you publish them. You don't have to be *selling* your app, you can give it away for free too.